# Adding marker to mapbox in flutter application

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mapbox

I've created a map using `Mapbox` API in `flutter` application, and used the `animateCamera` method which working perfectly, but I need to add a marker on the specific location after moving the camera .. here is the code I've used :

```dart
  Future<void> movingCameraToLocation(double latitude, double longitude) async {
    await mapController.animateCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(
          bearing: 270.0,
          target: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
          tilt: 30.0,
          zoom: 21.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

now how to add a marker on the `Latlng` used in here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to take a look at [this example](https://github.com/tobrun/flutter-mapbox-gl/tree/master/example/lib) that is placing a symbol at a specific position of your map in flutter.

The class `PlaceSymbolBodyState` implements the method `_add`  which adds a symbol at the specified location `center`:

```js
  void _add(String iconImage) {
    controller.addSymbol(
      SymbolOptions(
        geometry: LatLng(
          center.latitude,
          center.longitude,
        ),
        iconImage: iconImage,
      ),
    );
    setState(() {
      _symbolCount += 1;
    });
  }
```